# rewriting a groupby using .agg (lambda) instead of .apply(lambda)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, lambda, group-by

Is it possible to re-write the expression below in terms of `.agg`?

I have

```
sampleGC.groupby(['prime_broker_id', 'country_name'], as_index=False).apply( lambda df, a, b: sum(df[a] * df[b]),'carry_rate', 'notional_current')
```

which outputs

```
prime_broker_id  country_name
CITI             AUSTRALIA       4.929853e+10
                 HONG KONG       2.565716e+11
                 INDONESIA       3.508484e+09
                 JAPAN           9.608675e+11
                 MALAYSIA        9.459922e+10
                 NEW ZEALAND     2.479546e+08
```

I would like to re-write it as:

```
sampleGC.groupby(['prime_broker_id', 'country_name'], as_index=False).agg(
        {"": lambda }
```

How can I get the same output  (shown above)  by re-writing the groupby in terms of `.agg` ? 
I prefer this format as I can easily rename the column and add other operation such as sum and averages

Many Thanks

Comment: If it's solely for column names, you can define `your_desired_name` function and `apply(your_desired_name)` with `**kwargs`.

Comment: not for column names only

Comment: It is not possible to do multiple column calculation using .agg.  Agg will perform aggregation operations on a single column of data.  If you need to use two columns or more then you must use something other than agg like apply.

Comment: thank you Scott that is helpful to know. is it possible to have multiple lambdas inside .apply() so I can perform different operations please?  something like : .apply ("column_name1: lambda , column_name2: lambda .....)  how can I do that please?

Comment: You do not need to do multiple lambdas in the apply. It is enough to have an additional calculated column (please see my answer below for details).

Comment: You can do something like `df.groupby('key')['col1','col2'].agg({'col1':'sum', 'col2':'mean'})`.  You cant use multiple lambda, however, you could go ahead and define your owns and do it that way.  `df.groupby('key')['col1','col2'].agg({'col1':f1, 'col2':f2})`.  Note, you can use agg because these are single column aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will be able to do it in the following way (with an additional calculated column in your dataframe):

```
sampleGC['calculated'] = sampleGC['carry_rate'] * sampleGC['notional_current']

res = sampleGC.groupby(['prime_broker_id', 'country_name'], as_index=False).apply(lambda gb: gb['calculated'].agg('sum'))
```

Comment: Yes i thought about that but it is not very efficient when you have multiple operations to do ....

Comment: What type of efficiency do you have in mind? Performance of execution?